# Buck converter voltage drop and brownout

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, buck, undervoltage, brownout

I was trying to build a 24 V to 5 V buck converter to create a shield that would power my Raspberry Pi4 via GPIO pins and also connect it to an accelerometer.

The issue is, after powering it up, it supplies the RPI4 for a while, and then suddenly it drops from 5.15 V to 4 V which causes a reset.

It's not a PSU issue for sure since I have used a plug-and-play MP1584en converter before.

[This](https://fscdn.rohm.com/en/products/databook/datasheet/ic/power/switching_regulator/bd9e302efj-e.pdf) is the IC that I've used and schematic is below. What did I miss this time, again?

[image: schematic]

[image: PCB]

Comment: Test it with a resistive load. Also, what's up with this grounding? There should be one or two vias in IC1 GND pad. This switching loop is terrible, tons of stray inductance.

Comment: This chip needs thermal vias in the exposed pad, expect about 0.8 W there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straying from the recommended layout is begging for problems unless you know the effects of thermal and inductive properties of traces. Crosstalk and positive feedback leads to oscillations and instability. Lack of thermal ground heatsink leads to thermal shutdown.

See any differences?

[image]

Trace the thermal resistance and size of the current loop of ground and input to output power from F1 to C7 to C2!  There is a good reason why they put the ground plane on top.  Yours is on the bottom. **If you sniff any expected resonance oscillations, or thermal issues, then you may know better what to do.**

"Bootstrap capacitor CBOOT shall be 0.1μF. Connect a bootstrap capacitor between SW pin and BOOT pin.
For capacitance of Bootstrap capacitor, take temperature characteristics, DC bias characteristics, etc. into consideration"
You have 1 uF of unknown type.

Comment: I've changed the CBOOT to 0.1μF and BOOM! It's rock solid 5V now! Ty so much. It's the first pcb I've ever made and after all the issues you've pointed, it's like magic that it still works.

Comment: The real acid test is a full load on-off-on for over/undershoot , ripple and temp rise

Comment: I'm on my way to install it back to my 3d printer now and we'll see. Maybe I should solder an Evil Eye next to the fuse :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a basic understanding about these things, I recommend you a cheap course by Robert Feranec. It’s an introductory course to Altium, but about building a switched power supply: https://academy.fedevel.com/courses/online-switching-power-supply-design-course

Usually when you have an interesting module, evaluation boards are also designed and available: they give you a ton of information. (Like Tony already mentioned the evaluation layout)

Usually the power traces tend to be wide, even poured in polygons. Signal traces are usually smaller (6 mills wide), but here that’s not of an issue. You should look into what the width of a trace does to resistance, capacitance and inductance. (The last two frequency related, a major component of the switching idea) And the more copper, the better the thermal resistance. (Which if you solder yourself can also be very disturbing, but that’s a thing you will find out later haha)

And what is ground? Ground is the return path of your signals and power. Something goes in, then it also has to get out. The return path has to be without to many obstacles and unbroken. That’s why you find a lot of pcb’s with a ground plane.

Robert also has a ton of movies on youtube about these things.

Comment: It seems like the exact thing that I need to study. He also has a YouTube channel for the old versions btw. Thanks a lot.